# Matrix Class: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I have a Matrix4 class derived from/extending the Matrix base class (a template class). The methods of the template classes are declared and defined in the same header file.

I have only copied the portion of the "Matrix4" class that is giving the error. The same error occurs on lines 10 & 13. I cannot see any missing variables or arguments. I have tried taking away the parenthesis, but to no avail.

I have searched for a clue as to what I may be doing wrong, but I haven't found anything helpful in the similar questions on this website... I would really appreciate the help.

The Matrix4 class giving the error:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix4 : public Matrix<T, 4>
{
public:
    Matrix4() { }

    inline Matrix4 InitOrthographic(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T near, T far)
    {
        const T width = (right - left);
        const T height = (top - bottom);
        const T depth = (far - near);  //error occurs here

        (*this)[0][0] = T(2)/width; (*this)[1][0] = T(0);        (*this)[2][0] = T(0);        (*this)[3][0] = -(right + left)/width;
        (*this)[0][1] = T(0);       (*this)[1][1] = T(2)/height; (*this)[2][1] = T(0);        (*this)[3][1] = -(top + bottom)/height;
        (*this)[0][2] = T(0);       (*this)[1][2] = T(0);        (*this)[2][2] = T(-2)/depth; (*this)[3][2] = -(far + near)/depth;  //and here

        (*this)[0][3] = T(0);       (*this)[1][3] = T(0);        (*this)[2][3] = T(0);        (*this)[3][3] = T(1);  

        return *this;
    }
```

The Base Matrix class:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix() { }
        virtual ~Matrix() { }
        Matrix(const Matrix& other) { *this = other; }

        inline Matrix InitIdentity();   //defined in the same header, but left out here to save space
        inline Matrix InitTranslation(const Vector<T, D-1>& r);
        inline Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& rhs);
        inline Matrix operator*(const Matrix<T,D>& r) const;

        inline const T* operator[](int index) const { return m[index]; }
        inline T* operator[](int index) { return m[index]; }

    private:
        T m[D][D];
};
```

There are no errors in the base "Matrix" class, only in the derived "Matrix4" class.

If the code looks familiar, it's because I'm following a [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss3AnSxJ2X8&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5).

Comment: There is no line numbers in the code above. so 10 and 13 does not make sense. which line is causing the error? I dont have any error...

Comment: This code is full of errors example returning `Matrix` in class methods.

Comment: I added comments to indicate where the errors occured. e.g. the _const T depth = (far - near);_ line and the _(*this)[0][3] = T(0);  (*this)[1][3] = T(0);  (*this)[2][3] = T(0);  (*this)[3][3] = T(1);  //and here_

Comment: Which compiler is this on?

Comment: MinGW 4.8.1 using the Code::Blocks IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it compiles successfully under MS Visual C++

```
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix() { }
        virtual ~Matrix() { }
        Matrix(const Matrix<T, D>& other) { *this = other; }

        inline Matrix<T, D> InitIdentity();   //defined in the same header, but left out here to save space
        inline Matrix<T, D> InitTranslation(const Vector<T, D-1>& r);
        inline Matrix<T, D>& operator=(const Matrix<T, D>& rhs);
        inline Matrix<T, D> operator*(const Matrix<T,D>& r) const;

        inline const T* operator[](int index) const { return m[index]; }
        inline T* operator[](int index) { return m[index]; }

    private:
        T m[D][D];
};

template<typename T>
class Matrix4 : public Matrix<T, 4>
{
public:
    Matrix4() { }

    inline Matrix4<T> InitOrthographic(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T near, T far)
    {
        const T width = (right - left);
        const T height = (top - bottom);
        const T depth = (far - near);  //error occurs here

        (*this)[0][0] = T(2)/width; (*this)[1][0] = T(0);        (*this)[2][0] = T(0);        (*this)[3][0] = -(right + left)/width;
        (*this)[0][1] = T(0);       (*this)[1][1] = T(2)/height; (*this)[2][1] = T(0);        (*this)[3][1] = -(top + bottom)/height;
        (*this)[0][2] = T(0);       (*this)[1][2] = T(0);        (*this)[2][2] = T(-2)/depth; (*this)[3][2] = -(far + near)/depth;

        (*this)[0][3] = T(0);       (*this)[1][3] = T(0);        (*this)[2][3] = T(0);        (*this)[3][3] = T(1);  //and here

        return *this;
    }
};
```

and I do not know what happening with `Vector` class because I replaced it with int

Comment: not quite, you retuns wrong types, look at ansver closely.

Comment: in template classes you must return a template objects

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but I'm still receiving the same error in the same places... Is it maybe a difference between the compilers? I had the methods returning Matrix4<T> in the beginning, but I removed it in my attempts to find the problem

Comment: did you have try to remove () from `(far - near);`

Comment: Please describe the changes that you made in OP's code.

Comment: also try to remove const statement before your width, height and depth calculations

Comment: Just did. Removed the parenthesis and now I'm getting an _"expected primary-expression before ';' token|"_ error. It seems to be occurring with only the _"near"_ and _"far"_ arguments though... I replaced the whole assignment with just _"const T depth = top;"_ and it works. No changes when I remove the _const_ from in front of the calculations

Comment: I can not tell you more, because i have not access to Code::Blocks IDE at this moment.

Comment: It works after I changed the variable names in the method's argument list (shown in my answer). Thanks for the help. I changed my code to return the correct template _Matrix<T, D>_ instead of just _Matrix_. I'll look for any previous declarations or #defines that may have been conflicting with the arguments. How do you mark a question answered? xD

Comment: there is accept flag under arrows up down for answer vote. You will see it after mouse hovers this area

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution! Thanks for the help!

I changed my argument variable names from "far" & "near" to "m_near" & "m_far", and now it works. I think it may have been a conflict with a #define or another method in the class somewhere within the code.

It compiled and ran without errors. I couldn't find the cause of the original problem causing the conflict/error. The change seems to have fixed the problem, so I don't see the need to look too long or hard.

The *const*, before the variable declarations within the method, doesn't seem to create any undesired effects as-of-yet, so I'll keep it there.

Fixed code from the *Matrix4* class:

```
inline Matrix4<T> InitOrthographic(T left, T right, T m_near, T m_far, T bottom, T top)
{
    const T width = right - left;
    const T height = top - bottom;
    const T depth = m_far - m_near;  

    (*this)[0][0] = T(2)/width; (*this)[1][0] = T(0);        (*this)[2][0] = T(0);        (*this)[3][0] = -(right + left)/width;
    (*this)[0][1] = T(0);       (*this)[1][1] = T(2)/height; (*this)[2][1] = T(0);        (*this)[3][1] = -(top + bottom)/height;
    (*this)[0][2] = T(0);       (*this)[1][2] = T(0);        (*this)[2][2] = T(-2)/depth; (*this)[3][2] = -(m_far + m_near)/depth;
    (*this)[0][3] = T(0);       (*this)[1][3] = T(0);        (*this)[2][3] = T(0);        (*this)[3][3] = T(1);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: "far" and "near" are commonly used to adorn pointer types for some odd computers (which MSVC used to target) so that may be where they are parsed. Strict C++ says that they are not keywords though, so your code should have been accepted as valid regardless.

Comment: I think I may have a variable or #define somewhere else in the code, but I can't find anything. @Mykola said he successfully compiles on MS Visual C++, so I think it may be the compiler or simply how the IDE entered the project into the command-line

Comment: Backward compatibility ftw.